# Can I apply numbered lines of source code with css using only <br>?

Tags: css, browser, numbers, lines

I'd like to apply numbered source code to particular tag like <br>... I provide two examples, the one is well formed but don't work, the second is well formed and it works.. what can I do to get woirking the first example?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>[Number Lines]</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  <!--
    body {
      background-color: #1F242C;
    }
    .title {
      color: #E6E6FA;
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, FreeMono, 'Nimbus Mono L', monospace;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-variant: normal;
      margin: 45%;
    }
    .code {
      background-color: #32363c;
      border: #858687 1px solid;
      border-radius: 7px;
      color: #E6E6FA;
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, FreeMono, 'Nimbus Mono L', monospace;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 20px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
    }
    .code {
      counter-reset: listing;
    }
    br {
      counter-increment: listing;
    }
    .code br:before {
      color: gray;
      content: counter(listing, decimal-leading-zero);
      margin-left: 3ex;
      left: -3ex;
      position: relative;
      width: 2.5ex;
   }
  -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<br><br><br>
<table class="code" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" width="70%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="title">Example</span><br>
      line of source code<br>
      line of source code<br>
      line of source code<br>
      line of source code<br>
      line of source code<br>
      line of source code<br>
      line of source code<br>
      line of source code<br>
      line of source code<br>
      line of source code<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

This example don't work while the example below work great!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>[Number Lines]</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  <!--
    body {
      background-color: #1F242C;
    }
    .title {
      color: #E6E6FA;
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, FreeMono, 'Nimbus Mono L', monospace;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-variant: normal;
      margin: 45%;
    }
    .code {
      background-color: #32363c;
      border: #858687 1px solid;
      border-radius: 7px;
      color: #E6E6FA;
      font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, FreeMono, 'Nimbus Mono L', monospace;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-style: normal;
      line-height: 20px;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
    }
    .code {
      counter-reset: listing;
    }
    code {
      counter-increment: listing;
    }
    .code code:before {
      color: gray;
      content: counter(listing, decimal-leading-zero);
      margin-left: 3ex;
      left: -3ex;
      position: relative;
      width: 2.5ex;
   }
  -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<br><br><br>
<table class="code" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" width="70%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="title">Example</span><br>
      <code>line of source code</code><br>
      <code>line of source code</code><br>
      <code>line of source code</code><br>
      <code>line of source code</code><br>
      <code>line of source code</code><br>
      <code>line of source code</code><br>
      <code>line of source code</code><br>
      <code>line of source code</code><br>
      <code>line of source code</code><br>
      <code>line of source code</code><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Why I cannot use <br> to obtain the same result? Where I wrong? Thanks for any reply to my ask...

Comment: You have to use at least some tag, as you can see: `code {counter-increment: listing;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the line numbers included when you use `br`, because most browsers just treat `<br>` as a line breaking command, with no styleability, no matter what CSS and HTML specications might say.

Moreover, in the minority of browsers that try to take`br` seriously as a styleable element, your could would append the line number to a line. This is what happens with your code in Opera.

If you use the following instead, then Opera dispays the line numbers as desired:

```
 .code br {
      content: "\a " counter(listing, decimal-leading-zero);
      white-space: pre;
 }
```

However, the practical conclusion is that if line numbers are relevant, put them into document content. If not, omit them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use at least some tag, as you can see at the working code

```
code {counter-increment: listing;}
```

You can use , but idk if its posible without tags... :P